# how to python-oauth2

Tags: python, installation, oauth-2.0

I install python-oauth2 with `pip install oauth2` and I find the dir named 'oauth2' in `/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages`
But `from pyoauth2 import Client,AccessToken` say: no moudles named pyoauth2
Then, I changed `pyoauth2` to `oauth2`, same status.
I download the source code from https://github.com/douban/douban-client

Answer (score 3):

I think you are installing the wrong package. Try with `pip install pyoauth2`.

`oauth2` is a different package and does not define `AccessToken`.

It that works you can `pip uninstall oauth2`

Comment: U are right. I found the reason.  'pip' will put the code into '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages' but this path is not in my 'sys.path'. I tried to add this path to 'sys.path' with 'sys.path.append(\'path\')', but when i 'quit()', it disapperaed again.So, how to append path forever?

Comment: use `virtualenv` (together with pip) it is the de-facto standard for managing python packages installation

Answer (score 0):

Have you had problems with pip in the past?

Also have you tried to simply import oauth2 without specifying Client and AccessToken.

I pip installed oauth2 (windows) and AccessToken wasn't not found.

Also, are you running python in a separate terminal from the one which you called the pip install? You will have to restart python.

Worst case scenario, restart your machine.

Does any of this help?